# from both ends of the spectrum

Tags: idioms

Let's say you have a girlfriend. As the saying goes, opposites attract, and you want to use this idiom regarding your huge difference from each other:

> "We are like **from both ends of the spectrum**, but we love each other no matter what."

Did I use it correctly without missing something? I think you will hear it often from britons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say

... from opposite ends of the spectrum